# CData not being parsed with NSXmlparser

Tags: ios, ipad, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser, cdata

I receive response in the form of xml from a service,which i parse using nsxmlparser.
In an instance i received an xml where the content is same in two tags.(duplicate item as in below xml)

Xml received:

```
<UserGeneratedContentItem>
    <link
      rel="details"
      uri="http://api.test.no/test.Ugc/vivo/usergeneratedcontentitem/16046" />
    <Data><![CDATA[<Type>Note</Type><Description>**6000 characters**</Description><Page>6</Page><ChapterNumber>1</ChapterNumber><ChapterTitle>Etikk og filosofi</ChapterTitle><Uri>http://api.test.no/test.Ugc/vivo/usergeneratedcontentitem/6</Uri><Data><StickyNotes><StickyNote name="icon_2" X="215.8" Y="352.7" note="**6000 characters**" dateTime="null" popupX="940" popupY="119" popupWidth="300" popupHeight="180" formatedDate ="2012-12-28-18-20-47" iconImage="1003"/></StickyNotes></Data>]]></Data>
  </UserGeneratedContentItem>
  <UserGeneratedContentItem>
    <link
      rel="details"
      uri="http://api.test.no/test.Ugc/vivo/usergeneratedcontentitem/16046" />
    <Data><![CDATA[<Type>Note</Type><Description>**6000 characters**</Description><Page>6</Page><ChapterNumber>1</ChapterNumber><ChapterTitle>Etikk og filosofi</ChapterTitle><Uri>http://api.test.no/test.Ugc/vivo/usergeneratedcontentitem/6</Uri><Data><StickyNotes><StickyNote name="icon_2" X="215.8" Y="352.7" note="**6000 characters**" dateTime="null" popupX="940" popupY="119" popupWidth="300" popupHeight="180" formatedDate ="2012-12-28-18-20-47" iconImage="1003"/></StickyNotes></Data>]]></Data>
  </UserGeneratedContentItem>
```

6000 characters include alphabet,arithmatic & general punctuation marks which would be encoded.

Prob:

In  -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
method content in **CDATABlock** variable is not same in both cases(two tags).in one instance it gives me all 6000 characters and in the other instance it gives me only few may be around 300 characters.The text (6000 characters) is same in both cases which i confirmed.

What could be the reason? Can someone help me may be anybody who faced such issue earlier like me.

Tnx in advance.Plz let me know if something is not clear or not understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats what cdata is for -- it shouldnt be parsed

**CDATA - (Unparsed) Character Data**

src: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

PCDATA should be parsed

---

you gotta save the block of NSData (may be called N times, so you have to concat that stuff) and -in your case- then parse the result as separate XML

Comment: TnQ very much for the suggestion Dail-Djan.What i am doing is exactly the same.I am picking the data of the CDATA and forming an xml and parsing it again.My prob is that the data present in CDATA block is not available at a go sometimes.I understood that i have to append the text as it may be called N times.My doubt is how can i know the end of the CDATA iteration (Nth time) so that i can from an xml and parse it again.It would be more helpful if you a have sample else suggestion would also do.Tnq once again please share your thoughts it really helps me a lot.

Comment: update:It happend in my case that CDATA is being called N times and for now i have used a flag to append the text and parse it again.Currently in my response the CDATA block ends with </Data> and when encountering </Data> i am concluding the end of CDATA block and initiate parsing as a new xml,Which works as long as my response ends with </Data> and the content in the block doesn't have a text as </Data>.Is there a way(like a delegate method) where i can know the end of CDATA block,which would be the concrete solution rather than depending on a flag and a text.  TNQ once again.

Comment: the end is reached, when another delegate method of NSXMLParser is called I guess... :/ sorry.. this call works analogous to `parser:foundCharacters:`

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the following function along with other NSXMLParser function. It will then start taking care of CDATA block.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
{    
    NSString *someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}
```

You can NSLog someString, and it will show you the contents of CDATA block.

Comment: -1 what does it help? :) && this is not the whole CDATA block anyways, this is the fragment the parser found this time && (I do this too all the time ^^) one shouldnt assume NSUTF8String here, one should use the encoding determined by the parser :)