# Recursive loop over DDXMLDocument objective-c

Tags: objective-c, recursion, kissxml

I would like to loop recursively over DDXMLDocument, and to change the elements attributes.

How can I do it ? I currently have the document and the root element:

```
DDXMLDocument *theDocument = [[DDXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:content options:0 error:&error];
    DDXMLElement *rootElement = theDocument.rootElement;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

postfix tree walk implemented:

```
-(void)processNode:(DDXMLNode *)node {
    if(node.kind == DDXMLElementKind) {
       //...
       for(DDXMLNode *child in node.children) {
           [self processNode:child];
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be like this: -(void)processNode: (DDXMLNode *) node

Comment: Thanks. BTW, if I send the DDXMLDocument as the first root to the method it also parses the <?xml>. How can I send it without this element?

Comment: There should be a node type element and actually you should  check that in processNode using an if

Comment: I still have a problem. What if my XML looks like this? <html><[CDATA[ <body></body>]]></html> ? the amount of found children is only 1 - the HTML it can't omit the CDATA.. I need the CDATA since I have &nsbp in one of the div's content

Comment: .. thats whats CDATA is for -- CDATA is not parsed. (Just last week I answered that on SO .. you have collect the NSData and parse using another instance of the parser) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070750/cdata-not-being-parsed-with-nsxmlparser/14072073#14072073 (this applies to NSXMLParser but the idea is the same)

Comment: `NSString *cData = [childNode stringValue];` -- feed that into a XML parser

Comment: I didn't understand the last comment - what can I do in case of having &nsbp?

Comment: get all the cdata as one huge string and feed that as new content into a new parser

Comment: theDocument stringValue is null !